# Creating selectbox dynamically

Tags: php

in my website i am using an elements array to define all my form elements in a config file.
it's working fine now what i need is 2 Selectboxes that will be generated dynamically.
first selectbox should contains month names from Jan-Dec and second selectbox should contain years from current year to +10.

Please suggest how may i configure this situtation efficently?

thanks in advance.

```
$ELEMENTS["name"]  = array("label"=>"Username", "type"=>"text", "name"=>"user_name", "width" => "50", "validationtype"=>"text");
$ELEMENTS["email"] = array("label"=>"E-Mail",  "type"=>"text", "name"=>"e_mail", "width" => "50", "validationtype"=>"email");
$ELEMENTS["birthdate"] = array("label"=>"Date of birth",  "type"=>"text", "name"=>"birth_date", "width" => "50", "validationtype"=>"datel");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can. Typically the example you gave are for generating a `<INPUT ...>` tag and a selectbox is created by a `<SELECT ...>` tag. In addition, this tag includes a list of options like this:

```
<select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Inputs are:

```
<input type="text" name="car" value="" width="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For year you can use the following

```
for($i = date('Y') ; $i < date('Y') + 10 ; $i++)
 $YEARS["name"] = $i ;



For month 

for($i = 1 ; $i <=12 ; $i++)
$MONTHS = date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$i));
```

Hop this would help